# passing two values (one from text, one hidden) using html and php

Tags: php, html

I really struggle here and I spent much time on a solution but it seems that I missing something here.

So I have one page that I have 2 values:

```
$semesterID = $_GET['semesterID'];
$semesterID_old = $semesterID;
```

I do this as I want to pass 2 values on my next page. I am trying to do that with this:

```
    <form action=ed_semester_v2.php method="post">
    
    <div id="name">
    <h2 class="name">Semester ID</h2>
    <input class="subjectname" type="text" name="sem_id" id="sem_id" value= "<?php echo $semesterID; ?> " /> <br>     
    </div>

     <input type="hidden" name="semesterID_old" value= "<?php  $semesterID_old; ?>"/>

    <button type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">SAVE CHANGES</button>
    
 </form>
```

The one $semesterID pass fine to the next page but the semesterID_old no. Just to clarify that the semesterid might change by the user and that's ok.

In my next page, I use this code:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $first_name=$_POST['sem_id'];
    $last_name=$_POST['sem_name'];
    $semesterID_old= $_POST['semesterID_old'];
    if (empty($last_name)) {
    echo "Name is empty";
    } else {
    $query = "UPDATE semesters SET name = '$last_name' where semesterid='$first_name'";
    }
     if (!mysqli_query($dbconnect, $query)) {
    die('An error occurred when submitting your review.');
} else {
 // echo "Thanks for your review.";
    
    }
}    

echo $first_name;   
echo $semesterID_old;
```

First_name is fine but semesterID_old says that's undefined.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Typo.  When outputting the two values to the page, the one which works has an `echo` and the one which doesn't work does not have an `echo`.  You simply forgot to output the second value.

Comment: @David that seems to work, but I don't understand why I need echo to pass the value. I don't want to print it in the first place. I though just put in the value as it is ti will work. Thanks

Comment: *"I don't understand why I need echo to pass the value"* - Then why did you use `echo` for the first value, `$semesterID`?  *"I don't want to print it in the first place"* - If the browser needs to send the value to the server then the browser needs to have that value.  Overall the flow is that you need to put the values on the client which would then send them to the server as part of that form.

Answer (score -1):

Just change `echo semesterID_old;` to `echo $semesterID_old;`

Comment: sorry for the typo. In that case, I don't get anything printed.